# React doesn't remap Array from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically we have list component, something like this:

```
{this.state.answers[0] ? this.state.answers.map(answer =>
<li key={answer._id}>{answer.text}</li>) : null}
```

And when I update state component is re rendering but mapped list stay the same even when in `this.state` new, different data, list use old data. 
Is that some kind of bug or what? Why list doesn't remap not after updating state not even after re rendering?

Comment: Are you getting any warnings or errors in the console? There's not much to go off here, but my guess is you're entering a duplicate value without setting a unique `key` prop. Try `this.state.answers.map((answer, idx) =>
<li key={'answer-' + idx}>{answer.text}</li>)`

Comment: this.state.answers[0] can be replaced with this.state.answers.length > 0. Since answers is an array, you should not be pushing into the same array. slice() the array into a new array, and then push.

Comment: no it doesn't help I use _id from mongoDb so it always unique.

Comment: So you're using  `_id` as the `key` prop? If so, then you should include more information in your question.

Comment: Have you tried using the `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` life cycle method?  You might find you're not setting the new answers in state when the component receives new state/props causing the list to remain the same.

Comment: can you show the code which is setting the updated answers?

Comment: just simply trough handler ```this.setState({answers: [newArray]});```

Comment: ```shouldComponentUpdate``` doesn't help too, it just re render component, but problem that even after re render mapped list stay doesn't update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved mapped element, into separate component which use states and handlers from parent element and now it works.

```
{this.state.answers[0] ? this.state.answers.map(answer =>
    <Answer
         key={answer.displayOrder}
         answer={answer}
         optionsForSelect={this.state.optionsForSelect}
         _setRecommended={this._setValueForRecommended.bind(this, answer.displayOrder)}
         _setExclude={this._setValueForExclude.bind(this, answer.displayOrder)}
    />) : null}
```

It works because all props "besides handlers" in `Answer` I keep in his own state and use `componentWillReceiveProps` where I update states, to force re rendering for each mapped element, and finally it works.